# How to return the day using date in xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to return the day using date in xslt.

Input :

```
<root>
  <date meetingdate="20 Jun 2019" meetingJetbetclubid="Forbury Park Harness"/>
</root>
```

Output should be:

```
<date-format>Tue:Forbury Park Harness</date-format>
```

Tried code :

```
<xsl:template match="root/date">
  <date-format>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@meetingdate,':',@meetingJetbetclubid)" />
  </date-format>
</xsl:template>
```

My tried code not work9ing as expected. I am using XSLT 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a trivial problem if your date were in YYYY-MM-DD format. Then you would just need to format it as day-of-week.

As it is, you need to start by converting the given date to YYYY-MM-DD:

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:variable name="date-parts" select="tokenize(@meetingdate, ' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="m" select="index-of (('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'), $date-parts[2])"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(concat($date-parts[3], format-number($m, '-00'), format-number(number($date-parts[1]), '-00')))" />
    <date-format>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date($date, '[FNn,*-3]:')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="@meetingJetbetclubid" />
    </date-format>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamKY